# Flutter Android studio keep getting gradle error?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, mobile

I am trying to make my first flutter project on android studio, but I keep getting this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     AAPT: error: failed to open APK: Invalid file.



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 9s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to use vs code and I recieved the same error.

note: my gradle.properties file looks like this in android studio

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Assistance of this would be great as I have been trying to solve for 2 days. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you using any drawables xml?

Comment: I don't think so, but how would I be able to check?

Comment: go to android directory in terminal by `cd android` then run gradle build
`./gradlew build --stacktrace`

Comment: I ran the command and I got a build fail

Comment: it says ``` What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     AAPT: error: failed to open APK: Invalid file.
```

Comment: Review your pubspec.yaml may be there is some plugin out of dated that is too old. Also have a lokk at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42310 is it same?

Comment: my yaml file deems ok and no those errors are different

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by going to

```
    android > app > build.gradle
```

change

```
    compileSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 28
```

to

```
    compileSdkVersion 29
    targetSdkVersion 29
```